# How to convert List[String] to Strings in Scala

Tags: scala

I am struggling with Scala right now.
I have a map where the values is a list of strings `Map[String, List[String]]` I want to get value and separate with comma to pass as argument to a function.

I have the following

```
def blah (myMap: Map[String, List[String]]) {

var test = List() // I am trying to create a new object and append to this List
        
test ::= myMap.keys.foreach( key => new foo().withKey(key).withValues(myMap.get(key)))

}
```

My problem right now is in the `withValues` part because what I want is not array of values, I just want the values separated by comma like `withValue(value1, value2, ...)`
How can I accomplish that? Also is the way I am appending to the list correct?
Just to be clear what I am trying to do it's for my variable `test` to be something like

```
val test = List(new foo().withKey(key).withValues(value1, value2),
            new foo().withKey(key2).withValues(value3),
            new foon().withKey(key3).withValues(value4))
```

However, because I am trying to make this general where I don't know the number of keys and values the function will get, I am trying to use the for loop.

Comment: Do you mean variadic function/method (varargs)? Like `myMap.map { case (key, values) => new foo().withKey(key).withValues(values.toSeq*) }.toList`?

Comment: My compiler does not like ``.toSeq*`` and basically i mean I have the following 

``val test = List(new foo().withKey(key).withValues(value1, value2),
            new foo().withKey(key2).withValues(value3),
            new foo().withKey(key3).withValues(value4))``

but I am trying to make more generic, instead of hard coding accept a key/value, then I can use for multiple functions

Comment: I think it was a typo, Mateusz meant `.toSeq:_*`.

Comment: No typo, newer versions of compiler allows `seq*` as well, see: [Scala 3](https://scastie.scala-lang.org/TYyjGVPDQP2qipMI9Cwhlg) [Scala 2](https://scastie.scala-lang.org/vlRcsjeFQcWnlfcXmKikiA). I also use it in [sbt config](https://github.com/scalalandio/chimney/blob/fa135670e325095da09e18785ac2bfc0c5877df4/build.sbt#L165), so I guess, with the right flags (`-Xsource:3`) it's usable with as old versions of Scala as 2.12.

Answer (score 1):

For implementing `withValue(value1, value2, ...)`:
you can define your function such as `def withValues(values: String*)`, for example:

```scala
def withValues(values: String*): Unit = {
    values.foreach(println)
}
```

then you can invoke this function:

```
scala> withValues("a")
a

scala> withValues("a", "b")
a
b

scala> val list = List("a", "b")
list: List[String] = List(a, b)

scala> withValues(list:_*)
a
b
```

But if you want to pass the all elements in list, I think it is more simple that define withValues as `def withValues(values: List[String])`, then the class Foo and function blah looks like:

```scala
class Foo {
    def withKey(key: String): Foo = {
        // do something ...
        println(key)
        this
    }

    def withValues(values: List[String]): Foo = {
        // do something ...
        values.foreach(println)
        this
    }
}

def blah(myMap: Map[String, List[String]]): List[Foo] = {
    myMap.map { case(k,v) => new Foo().withKey(k).withValues(v) }.toList
}
```

invoke blah:

```
scala> blah(Map("a" -> List("1"), "b" -> List("2", "3")))
a
1
b
2
3
res12: List[Foo] = List(Foo@636d4cdc, Foo@565b77ba)
```

Comment: You can convert a `List` to varargs if you don't have access to the existing `withValues` method and it only accept varargs though. Syntax is `myList:_*`.

Answer (score 1):

Variadic functions like:

```
def foo(strings: String*): Unit = ()
```

are intended to be called like

```
foo()
foo("value1")
foo("value1", "value2")
//...
```

However, these `Type*` are `Seq[Type]` underneath, so these lists of values are wrapped in `Seq` and then a single value is passed down.

If you already have a collection to pass there, you need it to be `Seq`, then the compiler won't complain when you do:

```
val list: List[String] = List("value")
foo(list.toSeq: _*) // : _* tells compiler it's a vararg
                    // instead of a s single value to wrap in Seq
```

In [Scala 3](https://scastie.scala-lang.org/TYyjGVPDQP2qipMI9Cwhlg), as well as [Scala 2.12/2.13 with `scalacOptions += "-Xsource:3"` flag](https://scastie.scala-lang.org/vlRcsjeFQcWnlfcXmKikiA) set up in your build tool, you can use shorter syntax:

```
val list: List[String] = List("value")
foo(list.toSeq*)
```

If the type is already `Seq` you can skip `.toSeq` (while `List`s, `Vector`s etc are subtypes of `Seq`, this particular interface often complains if you don't upcast collection to `Seq`).

Long story short, your code can be implemented as

```
// Scala 2 without -Xsource:3 flag
val test = myMap.map { case (key, values) =>
  new foo().withKey(key).withValues(values.toSeq: _*)
}.toList

// Scala 2.12/2.13 with -Xsource:3, Scala 3
val test = myMap.map { case (key, values) =>
  new foo().withKey(key).withValues(values.toSeq*)
}.toList
```